# Spotlight: "VolumeConfiguration.plist" missing. Is it required, and how to modify?

Tags: spotlight, smb

I am seeing inconsistency in how Spotlight is working on Shared Volumes and it appears the presence, or lack of, and the content of
`/Volumes/GodzillaClone/.Spotlight-V100/VolumeConfiguration.plist`
might be implicated in these inconsistencies.

I have multiple SMB volumes mounted. One of them used to be a local volume but has now been copied to a Mac mini server and I have it locally mounted: `smb://192.168.5.1/Godzilla`

The other two, locally mounted SMB volumes, were freshly created on the server.

While logged in on the Mac mini server I have removed the spotlight directory and re-enable spotlight on two volumes: 
`smb://192.168.5.1/PlexMedia_1`
`smb://192.168.5.1/PlexMedia_2`

and after being reactivated there is no longer a `.Spotlight-V100/VolumeConfiguration.plist`

`smb://192.168.5.1/Godzilla` does have a `VolumeConfiguration.plist`

This research started when I tried to remove the local spotlight cache using `mdutil -p` on one of the mounted volumes after making a new Spotlight database on the server. When my commands failed I began to check each volume and notice the differences.

```
mdutil -p  /Volumes/PlexMedia_1         
/System/Volumes/Data/Volumes/PlexMedia_1:
    Error: datastore publishing not implemented.

mdutil -i on  /Volumes/PlexMedia_1
/System/Volumes/Data/Volumes/PlexMedia_1:
Error: unable to perform operation.  (-403)
    Server search enabled.

mdutil -i on  /Volumes/PlexMedia_2
/System/Volumes/Data/Volumes/PlexMedia_2:
Error: unable to perform operation.  (-403)
    Server search enabled.

mdutil -i on  /Volumes/Godzilla   
/System/Volumes/Data/Volumes/Godzilla:
    Indexing enabled.

mdutil -s  /Volumes/PlexMedia_1     
/System/Volumes/Data/Volumes/PlexMedia_1:
    Server search enabled.

mdutil -s  /Volumes/PlexMedia_2     
/System/Volumes/Data/Volumes/PlexMedia_2:
    Server search enabled.

mdutil -s  /Volumes/Godzilla   
/System/Volumes/Data/Volumes/Godzilla:
    Indexing enabled.
```

```
tree -L 2 /Volumes/Godzilla/.Spotlight-V100 /Volumes/PlexMedia_1/.Spotlight-V100 /Volumes/PlexMedia_2/.Spotlight-V100 
/Volumes/Godzilla/.Spotlight-V100
├── Store-V2
│   └── 6501AE1D-13CE-4787-9786-2AEBA0D5E3C5
└── VolumeConfiguration.plist
/Volumes/PlexMedia_1/.Spotlight-V100
└── Store-V2
    └── D3AD2234-1A3A-46E1-919D-019D01D859B8
/Volumes/PlexMedia_2/.Spotlight-V100
└── Store-V2
    └── 5E345843-A537-4A5D-A986-DE5B6EE0FBED

9 directories, 1 file
```

I don't remember explicitly choosing to enable "Server search"

How is the plist created? I am hazarding a guess that this is a "defaults" setting for spotlight that can be changed using a "defaults..." command, but I don't know the command.

I am also curious why there is no plist created when spotlight is turned off and then on for those two volumes. Maybe it depends on whether sharing is turned on or off when it's initially indexed?

I add the rhetorical questions for keyword searching and to provide context, and in case it helps others, not necessarily to be answered.

I would appreciate any insights as I am not able to find much googling.